# How to map/extend an unmapped class from another bundle?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.5

I have a simple class which acts as entity in an own bundle (core) and want to use that class as doctrine entity. The bundle doesn't contain any information about mapping of that class or similar.

I need to extend that class, because another constructor logic is needed. This is done in the bundle web. I have created a mapping for the bundle containing the extended class, the mapping file is called **Doc.orm.yml**.

```
Acme\WebBundle\Entity\Doc:
  type: entity
  table: docs
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO

  fields:
    ...
```

Running the app results into

> Class "Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\Doc" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.

The mentioned class is the unmapped class from the core bundle.

How can I extend an unmapped class and use it with doctrine?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Have you considered switching to `.php` entity classes? Then you could simply inherit the other class.

Comment: But I need the annotations in both classes or?

Comment: You don't need to define your mapping in yml if you use PHP instead. And annotations (or: annontated properties) are inherited, too.

Comment: I don't want any mapping or annotations in the core bundle.

Comment: Why not? Simply declare the class as `abstract`, and Doctrine will ignore it.

Comment: It is a requirement to have the core without any dependencies.